# How to move this to a base class, its a Ruby enumeration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I read this article that explained how to make enumerations in Ruby, and also showed how to them enumerable like:

```
class Blah

 def Blah.add_item(key, value)
   @hash ||= {}
   @hash[key] = value
 end

 def Blah.const_missing(key)
   @hash[key]
 end

 def Blah.each
   @hash.each {|key, value| yield(key, value)}
 end

end
```

1. I have other enumerations that I need, can I create a base class somehow from this so I don't have to repeat the methods add_item, const_missng and .each for each one?
2. When creating a file for all my enums, I put it in /lib/enums.rb, is that a good practise?
3. should I be putting this class inside of a module i.e. I believe you do that for a namespace right?

Answer (score 2):

1. You can just use Blah as your base class.

   class C < Blah; end

   class D < Blah; end
2. I think I might just throw it in with the source code of each project it's used with. Yes, DIE, DRY, and all that, but that's mostly important in line-by-line code. It's a fairly common practice to merge external software with each project.
3. No. It's already a class, so it's using only one name. Put the module around the code that uses Blah, the project or section of a project. That will be large and more in need of namespacing.

Answer (score 2):

DigitalRoss's answer is good.  I'll present an alternative.  Suppose you'd like each of your enumerations to live in a module.  All you need is a little Enumeration module, like so:

```
module Enumeration

  include Enumerable

  def self.included(m)
    m.extend self
  end

  def each(&block)
    constants.find_all do |name|
      name =~ /^[A-Z_\d]+$/
    end.map do |name|
      [name, const_get(name)]
    end.sort_by(&:last).each(&block)
  end

end
```

When you need an enumeration, create a module for it, include `Enumeration`, and define your keys and values as constants with all-caps names.

```
module States
  include Enumeration
  INIT = 1
  RUN = 2
  DONE = 3
end
```

The module will respond to any of the methods provided by `Enumerable`:

```
p States.to_a
# => [["INIT", 1], ["RUN", 2], ["DONE", 3]]
```

You may find that you sometimes don't care what the values are, just that they are distinct.  Let's add to Enumeration a method `value` that makes it easy to create constants with auto-incrementing keys:

```
module Enumeration

  def value(name, value = next_value)
    const_set(name, value)
  end

  def next_value
    (map(&:last).max || 0) + 1
  end

end
```

Now let's have some planets:

```
module Planets
  include Enumeration
  value :MERCURY
  value :VENUS
  value :EARTH
end

p Planets.to_a
# => [["MERCURY", 1], ["VENUS", 2], ["EARTH", 3]]
```

Of course, these enumerations are just collections of normal constants, so you can use them directly:

```
p Planets::MERCURY    # => 1
```